# iOS url scheme music parameters for direct song selection

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Anybody knows if the ios url scheme `music:` does have any parameters? Can we open a song directly with this scheme? I mean opening the Music app with a specific song or album directly selected, not just showing the start screen or the playing now section.

Comment: What does "open a song" even mean? Did you _try_ using this scheme and _see_ whether it does what you want?

Comment: i mean with a song or album directly selected in the library